# Ionic specific issue on getting window height in directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a div on resize reach fill the entire height of the window minus a certain amount.

For some reason I get the following error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: w.height is not a function
at scope.getWindowDimensions (app.js:283)
at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30230)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30503)
at done (ionic.bundle.js:24824)
at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25022)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:24963)
```

However, if I remove my ionic.bundle.js from the header, it works. (note that I am using this in the browser)

**Directive**

```
.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        console.log(w);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () { return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() }; };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
            scope.style = function (amount) { return {  'height': (newValue.h - amount) + 'px', 'width': (newValue.w - amount) + 'px' }; };
            scope.height = function (amount) { return { 'height': (newValue.h - amount) + 'px' }; };
        }, true);
        w.bind('resize', function () { scope.$apply(); });
    }
})
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<div id="pageContent" ng-style="height(75)" resize>
Stuff here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pageContent {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   z-index: 2;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't noticed, [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) does not implement those jQuery methods, you can use jQuery with angularjs if you like (not recomended) or you can use raw window object.

The `window` object doesn't have those function. You can find those functions when using jQuery but on raw javascript you only have `window.screen` where you have `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width` as well.

If can find a proper way to calculate this on this question: [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437786/4488121).

Or by simple using `w.screen.height` and `w.screen.width` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but, I thing you want get screen dimensions in your app, right?

Well, you don't need to use jQLite for this, you can inject `$window` and use `$window.screen`

Have a look at following [this ionicforum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-device-width-and-height/28372/19) thread and to understand how you can use `$window` to achieve your objective. You can also go through this article: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-get-page-height-width/ to understand how this works.

Hope this helps.